# Working with iPhone OS 3.2 only classes

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2, universal

How would you write a universal app that uses classes introduced in iPhone OS 3.2, such as `UIPopoverController` and `UISplitViewController`? On Jeff LaMarche's blog about this, Ole provides a method for instantiating these objects; you would instantiate a `UIPopoverController` like so: `[NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController") alloc]`.

This is fine for instantiating these classes in code but what about protocols and their methods? My iPad app uses a `UISplitViewController` and has a class that needs to conform to the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` and `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`. How would you declare this? And how would you work with a method such as the following?

`- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc 
      willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
           withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem 
        forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc`

where the method call requires `UISplitViewController` to be passed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, just like that, I see that this isn't a problem if you weak-link the UIKit framework. I found this right here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618889/universal-iphone-ipad-application-debug-compilation-error-for-iphone-testing).

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it there, since these `UISplitViewController*` etc only serves as a type for the compiler to do type-checking (unlike `[UISplitViewController alloc]` which an actual symbol needs to be linked).

Add a `@class UISplitViewController, UIPopoverController;` at the start of the file if it doesn't compile.