# Integrate MGSplitViewController in Universal App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a universal app for iPhone and iPad using [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad).

I'm going to start with a window based template (empty) but not sure how to integrate MGSplitView. The reference project is not good for me becouse it's only for iPad.

Does anyone know where to start? Any Tutorial?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796587/how-do-i-make-a-universal-iphone-ipad-application-that-programmatically-uses-ui

Comment: not a duplicate - that's talking about the Apple control UISplitViewController which is iPad-only and lacks other features of the MGSplitVieController.  What is not clear from the question is if dbgarage wanted to split the iPhone screen or not.