# dyld: Symbol not found: _MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification

Tags: dyld

I am building universal app which uses MPMoviePlayerViewController to play the video. Observing notification "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification". The app successfully runs in iPad simulator but throws following error when it runs in iPhone:-

dyld: Symbol not found: _MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
  Referenced from: /Users/veer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/27BC67AA-72D1-4DD2-9146-0126FCC8E90C/test.app/eReader
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
 in /Users/veer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/27BC67AA-72D1-4DD2-9146-0126FCC8E90C/test.app/eReader

Is any one having the same issue and got resolved?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to weak-link the MediaPlayer framework.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618889/universal-iphone-ipad-application-debug-compilation-error-for-iphone-testing/2622027#2622027) to see how to weak-link a framework.