# iOS 5 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, ios5

I have xcode 4.2.1. The simulator works perfectly if I select the iOS 4.3 SDK but for some reason is not recognizing the folder containing the iOS 5.0 SDK. 
Some solution? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Xcode>preferences>downloads

If for what ever reason your 5.0 simulator was removed this should allow you to re-add it.

Comment: Thanks @0x7fffffff, there are some pretty bonkers workarounds out there for this simple fix - I completely missed these options in preferences. Thanks heaps (and stacks)

Comment: In the current version of Xcode(7.3) to add other simulators it is under Xcode>Preferences>Components

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is to upgrade your Xcode to Xcode 4.3.

XCode 4.3 is the current stable version of Xcode and probably it'll fix you problem.

It's odd to see this happening on Xcode 4.2.1 but I wouldn't waste time trying to figure out what's wrong with this version.