# Unable to run new Titanium app on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Just created a new project and when trying to run on iPhone simulator I get the following error:

```
Accepted values:
   8.0
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--sim-version" value "7.1"
For help, run: titanium help build
```

I'm guessing it's due to the xCode update to the new version and the support for iPhone 6.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

I'm running against the latest Titanium SDK (3.3.0)

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459399/ios-simulator-only-list-the-latest-ios-version-how-can-i-set-earlier-versions

Comment: Check whether you have installed iOS 7.1 simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Ti 3.4.0, so update Titanium (Studio, SDK, NPM), then set up the newest version of Ti SDK in `tiapp.xml`, clean up your project and that's it!

(How to do the update): http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/09/announcing-our-ios-8-support-with-appcelerator-sdkstudio-3-4-0-release/