# Is it permited to inherit TWTweetComposeViewController? I have a crash on ios 6.0

Tags: ios, twitter, crash, selector

My app works on a device with 5.1 (ipad). But it crashed on 6.0 simulator. Please, see an error.

```
@interface TwitterViewController : TWTweetComposeViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TwitterVCDelegate> delegateTwitter;

@end
```

//In QuotesVC I call

```
TwitterViewController *tweetVC = [[TwitterViewController alloc] init];
tweetVC.delegateTwitter = self;
[tweetVC postWithQuote:[quotesArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
```

// my app has crashed

```
-[SLTwitterComposeViewController setDelegateTwitter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8d1bb0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SLTwitterComposeViewController setDelegateTwitter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8d1bb0'
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

**Edit** Everything works well If I doesn't inherit TWTweetComposeViewController.

```
   TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet =
    [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Initial Tweet Text!"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

I tested this code on ipad device 5.1 and ios simulator 6.0. It works well.

***Is it permited to inherit TWTweetComposeViewController?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my mind iOS 6 implicitly convert `TWTweetComposeViewController` to `SLTwitterComposeViewController`. `SLTwitterComposeViewController` don't have any `setDelegateTwitter:` method. That's why error occured.

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work in iOS 5 versions. Because you have included **twitter.framework** and it will be replaced as a **social.framework**. **So you need to check whether the device is iOS 6 or 5**. Here it is a links to integrate twitter for versions iOS 5 and iOS 6.

[iOS 6 Social framework](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Twitter_and_Facebook_into_iPhone_iOS_6_Applications)

[iOS 5 Twitter framework](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5)

Comment: If I add social.framework to my app I won't run on ios 5.1 device, because it hasn't this framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480765/how-do-i-weak-link-frameworks-on-xcode-4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778104/problems-building-for-both-ios4-3-and-ios5-0 these links will be helpful to u. you need to set both frameworks as optional

Comment: yes I tried. It's impossible to inherit SLComposeViewController because it doesn't allow to do this. serviceType is readOnly. I refactored my code and now I don't inherit twitter's classes. Thank you for help.