# Error debugging app on Iphone 3G with XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I have an app working on Iphone 3GS, Ipad and Iphone simulator.
Now I'm trying to test and debug on an Iphone 3G and I can't

Fist, XCode asked me to download some library. 
I did it!

Then, I had problem with the Architecture and searching on internet i found the solution. Setting the Architecture on armv6 and armv7

Now, when I start the app for debugging it show me this log:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.

There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.

This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreVideo" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreMedia" (not yet mapped into memory).
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-2123-32
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x2a03]
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x2a03]

warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
    Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 3

warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
        /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

    warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).

    warning: No copy of MobileSubstrate.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

    warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

    warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/RockExtensions/RockExtensions.dylib (file not found).

    warning: No copy of RockExtensions.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

    warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

    dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/9DDCE0DE-4B75-434C-B393-99AA847CAE0E/XXXX.app/XXXXX
      Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2622027

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use UIPopoverController in an iPhone application. UIPopoverController is not available in iPhone it is for iPad only. You can put a conditional to avoid the use of UIPopoverController at runtime in case of iPhone device.

Comment: I searched for UIPopoverController on my app and is used by ZBar's class ZBarCameraSimulator as a type for a property. Isn't my code, is from ZBar Library I think. I can't change it

But, is strange, becouse on an Iphone 4.0 it works correctly

Comment: The problem is not that he's calling UIPopoverController but that iOS can't find the UIPopoverController in its SDK when loading the app on the 3G phone. The linker reference to it should be a [weak link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3027213/154803) so that it is optional, this allows the app to load without resolving the reference.

Comment: I changed the library to Optional (is the same as weak?) and also crash and show me another Log with diferent problems. 

I don't see that as a solution