# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios

I am getting this error while running the application.Kindly provide some information on this error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UICollectionViewCell
```

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2622027/834998) helps you.

Comment: IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is not set to iOS 5?

Comment: If you ask a question, it's generally helpful to see the relevant part of your code. If it's short, you can post it in your question. Otherwise, you can post a Gist on Github. Or you could even share your entire project (e.g. through Dropbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
 make it proper in

```
Target->BuildSettings->IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 
Target->Summary->iOS Application Target.
```

UICollectionView & UICollectionViewCell is for iOS 6 and later and hence it may be set to lower version the error pops up