# error from debugger mi_cmd_stack_list_frames not enough frames in stack for all my projects

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, stack

Well I've got a serious problem with my application.When I want to build and run  one of my application I have the error :`error from debugger mi_cmd_stack_list_frames not enough frames in stack` and this for all my projects, so that shows it's not a problem which come from an app but from something else .So How can I solve this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: I believe this has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1372117